# In Postgresql, I counted/aggregated inventory based on part numbers, but want the query to only return results about a threshhold volume

Tags: postgresql, count, aggregate

For my company, I am writing a query that is aggregating/counting our inventory by part number.  This works well and returns a data set that shows the volume we have in inventory for each part number.

However, because we have a large number of part numbers where the volume is just 1, I would like to exclude any such part number from the results when the count falls under a certain threshhold, like 5.

I've looked at the FETCH, LIMIT, and other functions but they don't seem to capture what I need.

```
select "Part#", "Description", "Cond_Code", "PO_NUM", count(*)
from "Inventory" 

    group by "Part#","Description","Cond_Code", "PO_NUM"

    Order by "count" DESC,"Part#", "Description","Cond_Code", "PO_NUM"
```

This gives me the results where each part number total is displayed, but as I said, I would like to display only part numbers where the totals meet a certain minimum threshhold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a HAVING clause:

```
select "Part#", "Description", "Cond_Code", "PO_NUM", count(*) "Counter"
from "Inventory" 
group by "Part#","Description","Cond_Code", "PO_NUM"
having count(*) > 4
order by "Counter" desc, "Part#", "Description","Cond_Code", "PO_NUM"
```